# IPv4, IPv6, & hostname regex

Tags: java, javascript, regex, gwt

Im doing a field validation in GWT. I have a HUGE Regex (gwt only supports a subset of Java regex) that does successfully work for detecting ipv4,ipv6 & hostnames.

www.google.com

`192.168.1.1`

`2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334`

I need it to accept csv's of the above also and I cannot figure it out. I can get it to accept say csv's of 1 type but not when their interchanged.

I.E: `1.2.3.4,5.6.7.8` works

but not `1.2.3.4,2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334`.

I'm close and i know the regex is a monster but can anyone help?

```
private static final String IPV6_IPV4_HOSTNAME_VALIDATION_REGEX = ""
+ "^(((([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))(\\,)?)*$|^((([a-zA-Z]"
+ "|[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\\.)*([A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])(\\,)?)*$"
+ "|^((?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})):){6})(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})):(?:(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:25[0-5]"
+ "|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9]))\\.){3}(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9])))))))"
+ "|(?:(?:::(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})):){5})(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})):(?:(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]"
+ "|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9]))\\.){3}(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9])))))))"
+ "|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})))?::(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})):){4})(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})):(?:(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})))"
+ "|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9]))\\.){3}(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9])))))))"
+ "|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})):){0,1}(?:(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})))?::(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})):){3})(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})):(?:(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})))"
+ "|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9]))\\.){3}(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9])))))))"
+ "|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})):){0,2}(?:(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})))?::(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})):){2})(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})):(?:(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})))"
+ "|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9]))\\.){3}(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9])))))))"
+ "|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})):){0,3}(?:(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})))?::(?:(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})):)(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})):(?:(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})))"
+ "|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9]))\\.){3}(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9])))))))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})):){0,4}(?:(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})))?::)(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})):(?:(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})))"
+ "|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9]))\\.){3}(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])?[0-9])))))))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})):){0,5}(?:(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})))?::)(?:(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})))"
+ "|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})):){0,6}(?:(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4})))?::))))(\\,)?)*$";
```

Comment: This regex will be impossible to maintain even if you get it to work. Why not split it up into multiple regexes, and then applying them in succession in the Java code?

Comment: Keep in mind that domain names actually end with a dot, which is optinal (and usually omited). Also, don't forget IPs like ```64:ff9b::198.252.206.16```.

Answer (score 2):

Go back to the grammar and the regex will follow.

```
list := part ( ',' part)*

part := ipv4 | ipv6 | hostname
```

Now translate that "ABNF-like" grammar to Java:

```
private static String IPV4 = "…";
private static String IPV6 = "…";
private static String HOSTNAME = "…";

private static String PART = "(?:" + IPV4 + "|" + IPV6 + "|" + HOSTNAME + ")";
private static String LIST = "^" + PART + "(?:," + PART + ")*$";
```

Note: you should apply the same reasoning to your matching of IPv4, IPv6 and host names.

Comment: Awesome @Thomas I should have thought of that instead of manipulating the regex separate and deal with the string variables. I'll accept when I try n a hour or so. Thank guys I also I tried what others suggested with string split but it doesn't work I need regex to parse entire field you can't say loop through comma separated values and validate each one, it's entire field n one shot.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with GWT but perhaps you could just use String.split(",") to split the addresses up into an array, then trim and apply the validation regex on each item in the array.